# Defining custom provider and $injector:unpr Unknow provider

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Im trying to understand hows providers works and i make a test based in angularjs documentation and i wrote a simple provider :

```
(function( window, angular, undefined ){"use strict";
    function MyProviderExample(foo)
    {
      this.testdrive = function()
      {
        console.log(foo);
      }
      console.log("init");
    }
    angular.module('app',[])
    .provider('$myProvider',function (){
      var foo = "bar";
      this.$get = function()
      {
        return new MyProviderExample(foo);
      }
      console.log("ey....");

    }).config(function($myProvider){
      console.log("wut");
      $myProvider.foo = "foo";
    });
})(window, window.angular);
```

When i run the code always returns

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $myProvider
```

I was trying to understand what fails but i cant see my mistake, if someone can helps i appreciate

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to remove `function($myProvider)` from the `.config` section. Like this:

```
    angular.module('app', [])
    .provider('$myProvider', function () {            
        this.$get = function () {
            // --
        }
        console.log("loaded $myProvider");
    })
    .config(function(){
        console.log("loaded config");
    })
    .controller('Main',
        function main() {
            console.log('loaded mycontroller')
        });
```

What are you trying to do with $`myProvider.foo = "foo";`?